# Polymorphism and nested attributes

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, polymorphism, nested-attributes

I have the following polymorphic association set up with [acts_as_relation](https://github.com/hzamani/acts_as_relation)

[image: polymorphic association]

Model code:

```
class Email < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :detail
  validates_presence_of :address
end


class Detail < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_superclass
  has_many :emails
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :emails, allow_destroy: true
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as :detail
  validates_presence_of :username, :password
end
```

Migration code:

```
class CreateInfo < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :details, :as_relation_superclass => true do |t|
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateEmails < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :emails do |t|
      t.string :address
      t.string :address_type
      t.string :detail_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :username
      t.string :password

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I'm want to be able to have a form (eventually) that will allow multiple email addresses, addresses and so on. But I'm struggling to get it to work. I use HAML for whoever may reply with the view code, which is a lot more readable.

I have the form currently something like this:

```
views/users/_form.html.haml

= form_for(@user) do |f|
  - if @user.errors.any?
    #error_explanation
      %h2
        = pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error")
        prohibited this user from being saved:
      %ul
        - @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
          %li= msg
  .field
    = f.label :name
    = f.text_field :name
  .field
    = f.label :username
    = f.text_field :username
  .field
    = f.label :password
    = f.text_field :password
  = f.fields_for :emails do |ff|
    .field
      = ff.label :address, 'Email address'
      = ff.text_field :address
    .field
      = ff.label :address_type, 'Type'
      = ff.text_field :address_type
  .actions
    = f.submit
```

Comment: I'm not able to implement nested attributes. I think it would be easier if there was no polymorphism involved, but I am not sure that is the problem here - I think it has been resolved with acts_as_relation. However, I am struggling with nested attributes.

Comment: Could you provide more details about exact problem place. E.g. HTML generation, form submit, or simple quite nothing (nothing is created)?

Comment: I kept changing things around, but the problem was particularly with getting the form to work, either to show the fields, and when I got them to show - it complained about the input. I'm aware of putting into the controller something like `@emails = @user.email.build` or something like that. But all the tutorials I found did not expressly do this. http://rubysource.com/complex-rails-forms-with-nested-attributes/

Comment: Rails simply expects from client to have correct hash for your nested models. For example, for your emails case: `params[:user][:email_attributes]` should look like either as array of hashes, or as hash with not usable keys and values - the attributes for your email: `{:foo => {:address => 'a@a.com', :address_type => 'bar'}}`. In this case Rails should ignore `:foo` and create one `Email` as hash provided does not contain the `:id` key-value pair.

Comment: Check if that happens in your case and we could continue investigating your problem cause. As from source of `acts_as_relation` all methods described in `Detail` should be available in `User`, including required `emails_attributes=`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a problem with adding nested_attributes, it may be interesting to look on https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form

Comment: Exciting gem, I will check it out.